# How to programmatically set DurationBox value in jQuery Mobile DateBox2?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile, datebox

I am using the DateBox2 PlugIn for my jQuery Mobile webpage.

I get a duration in seconds from a JSON Webservice which can be as long as multiple days (e.g. 86400s).

I want to post this in to my text input using the standard DateBox2 duration display like 
"1 Day, 00:00:00", but all I get is the plain seconds value.

I tried some combinations of  .val(), .datebox("setTheDate", 86400), .datebox(callFormat, ...) but none of them seem to work.

Here is my input field:

```
<input class='period' type='text' readonly='readonly' data-role='datebox' data-options='{"mode": "durationbox", "showInitialValue": true, "useFocus": true}' />
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly use this:

$('element').trigger('datebox', {'method':'dooffset', 'type':'s', 'amount':86400}).trigger('datebox', {'method':'doset'});